# Mailchimp Issues

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Hellooo

I have been using the MailChimp API in my express app for a while and in past few days it is giving me an error. From what it seems like I need have a way to up update existing subscribers. This could be referencing the actual MailChimp website in audience preferences but I have been messing with it for two days now so i figured I would come here. Also, even if it is a new email that is being added, I still get this same error. Any help would be appreciated.

```
`The error states {"new_members":[],"updated_members":[],"errors":          [{"email_address":"new@new.gmail","error":"new@new.gmail is already a list member, do you want to update? please provide update_existing:true in the request body","error_code":"ERROR_CONTACT_EXISTS","field":"","field_message":""}],"total_created":0,"total_updated"     :0,"error_count":1,"_links"`
```

Here is my code with the exception of error messages, home route and port listening.

```
`const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const ejsMate = require('ejs-mate')


const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ urlencoded: true }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));



const https = require("https");

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.engine('ejs', ejsMate);




})   


// API data
app.post('/subscribe', (req, res) => {
   const firstName = req.body.firstName;
   const lastName = req.body.lastName;
   const email = req.body.email;

   const data = {
     members: [
        {
        email_address: email,
        status: "subscribed",
        merge_fields: {
            FNAME: firstName,
            LNAME: lastName
           }
       }
   ]
};

 const jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);

 const url = "https://us21.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/apikey";

 const options = {
   method: "POST",
   headers: {
    Authorization: "auth"
   }
 };

 const request = https.request(url, options, function (response) {
    if (response.statusCode === 200) {
        res.render('success');
    } else {
        res.render('error')
    }
    response.on("data", function (data) {
        console.log(JSON.parse(data));
    })
 }) 

  request.write(jsonData);
  request.end();
});
`
```